# ASM 'sall' command with single argument?

Tags: assembly

The sall instruction, in the form

```
sall  Src,Dest
```

translates into a left shift of Dest by Src

```
Dest=Dest<<Src
```

But I have no idea what this is:

```
   sall    -8(%ebp)
```

I would presume that its shifting -8(%ebp) left, but by how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

```
SAL r/m32, 1
```

means:

```
Multiply r/m32 by 2, once.
```

It appears that your assembler doesn't require the `, 1`, since it's easily inferred.

I just did a quick test here, and check this out:

```
    .globl f
f:
   sall -8(%ebp)
   sall $1, -8(%ebp)
```

Assemble and disassemble:

```
$ otool -tV example.o 
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
f:
0000000000000000    shll    -0x8(%ebp)
0000000000000004    shll    -0x8(%ebp)
$ otool -t example.o
example.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
0000000000000000 67 d1 65 f8 67 d1 65 f8
```

Note that both opcodes came out identically.